# Можно удалять, нельзя изменять

Tags: windows, права, доступ, ntfs

Как настроить права доступа к файлу таким образом. чтобы с ним можно было делать всё, кроме изменения содержимого. Т. е. должно быть можно удалить файл и создать другой с таким же именем, но записывать что-либо в уже существующий файл должно быть нельзя.

Зачем надо? Хочу использовать hardlink'и для помещения файла в несколько мест. Соответственно, при записи такого файла он изменится во всех местах, а мне это не надо. Поэтому хочу запретить запись.

Comment: Ну так, удаление и модификация - раздельные пермиссии... В стандартном интерфейсе всё есть...

Comment: @vp_arth, не вижу тут ничего про удаление: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWEq.png

Comment: ниже кнопочка дополнительно

Comment: @vp_arth, там всё то же самое.

Comment: Да ладно, ну ок. Добавить -> Выберите субъект -> вводишь юзера/группу -> ок -> отображение дополнительных разрешений

Answer (score 1):

Это закопано глубже, но есть чуть дальше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо запретить "Создание файлов / запись данных" и "Создание папок / дозапись данных"? Оно применится к файлу и на папку никак не повлияет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, точно сказать не могу. Юзал давно и не задокументировал. Надо просто попробовать "на кошках".